# Insert Python array with different values into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, arrays

How do I insert an array which has elements of different formats( like date, float and int) into MySQL table in a database using Python? I am very new to programming so please excuse me if I have made any simple mistakes

This is the code I've been trying :

```
f=open('xyz.txt')
d=f.readlines()
y=[x.split() for x in d]
print y
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user='root',passwd='***',db='name')
cur = db.cursor()
var_string = ','.join('%s' * len(y))
sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('%s');" % (var_string)
cur.execute(sql,y)
```

and this is how my array looks:

[['1', '"01/01/2007"', '0', '0.000', '10.14', '0.0000', '87'], ['1', '"01/01/2007"', '1', '0.000', '10.93', '0.0000', '87'], ['1', '"01/01/2007"', '2', '0.000', '11.78', '0.2540', '89'], ['1', '"01/01/2007"', '3', '0.000', '13.23', '0.5080', '90'], ['1', '"01/01/2007"', '4', '0.000', '14.43', '0.0000', '89'], ['1', '"01/01/2007"', '5', '0.000', '14.89', '0.0000', '88']]

Comment: there's no such thing as a "mysql workbench table". workbench is an INTERFACE to mysql, and it's the mysql DB server which contains your "table". And if you want to insert stuff using python, then I suggest you learn SQL and Python

Comment: [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL "formats" your query.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (string,integer) VALUES('George Orwell',1984);
```

But use only that formats you set at the creation of the table!
Don't save a string with 500 characters in a varchar or something like that.

Here a link if you need help choosing the right format: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html

But in the most cases you can use integer and varchar.

Answer (score 0):

(Side note: Have you thought about some kind of NoSQL setup? Most of these handle mixed types better.)

Now, as SQL does not allow for differing input types, you'll need to manage that yourself. My suggestion would be convert everything to strings, then just convert back on load. It may be helpful to have a second column that gives the type of the original data.